# How to convert Option[Try[_]] to Try[Option[_]]?

Tags: scala, option-type, traversable

I quite often use the function below to convert `Option[Try[_]]` to `Try[Option[_]]` but it feels wrong. Can be such a functionality expressed in more idiomatic way?

```
def swap[T](optTry: Option[Try[T]]): Try[Option[T]] = {
  optTry match {
    case Some(Success(t)) => Success(Some(t))
    case Some(Failure(e)) => Failure(e)
    case None => Success(None)
  }
}
```

Say I have two values:

```
val v1: Int = ???
val v2: Option[Int] = ???
```

I want to make an operation `op` (which can fail) on these values and pass that to function `f` below.

```
def op(x: Int): Try[String]
def f(x: String, y: Option[String]): Unit
```

I typically use for comprehension for readability:

```
for {
  opedV1 <- op(v1)
  opedV2 <- swap(v2.map(op))
} f(opedV1, opedV2)
```

PS. I'd like to avoid some heavy stuff like scalaz.

Comment: The definition of `swap` looks reasonable. I'm not sure what more you could want from it.

Comment: One thought: this operation is usually (idiomatically?) called `sequence` rather than `swap`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like `Try { option.map(_.get) }` will do what you want.

Comment: In my view throwing and catching the exception like this has enough overhead (e.g. at runtime but more importantly for readers) that the OPs implementation is preferable, even if it's a little less concise.

Comment: What is the overhead of throwing exception (beyond instantiating it and filling in the stack, which would have already been done by now)? I am not aware of it being significantly larger than calling a function. In any event, I figure, if one is concerned with overhead of throwing exceptions, he should not be using `Try` to begin with. Or scala for that matter (there are things in scala that pose a lot more overhead and are a lot harder to avoid than exceptions). Just stick with "C" and gotos to be sure to minimize your overhead :)

Comment: That's why I emphasized the overhead for human readers. I often grep for `.get` calls on `Try` or `Option` as a quick measure of the health of a project that's new to me, and I don't make exceptions because the authors are being clever in order to save a couple of lines and avoid a pattern match. :)

Comment: Well, that's too bad. I always make exceptions for clever people. I find that they are hard enough to come by to deserve to be treated differently than the stupid ones every now and again ;)

Comment: Agreed with @Dima. Exception overhead is second to none, comparing to other stuff. What I've learned so far is just: most of the time don't use util.Try; it doesn't play nicely with standard library.

Comment: @Dima If Josh Bloch's micro benchmark from *Effective Java* is anything to go by, I'd expect that throwing an exception only to catch immediately is significantly less performant than returning it as a value. Regardless of performance, in an expression-oriented language like Scala, manipulating values rather than throwing exceptions is considered more idiomatic. I'm with Travis on this one.

Answer (score 8):

The [cats](http://typelevel.org/cats/) library allows you to *sequence* an `Option` to a `Try` very easily:

```
scala> import cats.implicits._
import cats.implicits._

scala> import scala.util.{Failure, Success, Try}
import scala.util.{Failure, Success, Try}

scala> Option(Success(1)).sequence[Try, Int]
res0: scala.util.Try[Option[Int]] = Success(Some(1))

scala> Option(Failure[Int](new IllegalArgumentException("nonpositive integer"))).sequence[Try, Int]
res1: scala.util.Try[Option[Int]] = Failure(java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: nonpositive integer)

scala> None.sequence[Try, Int]
res2: scala.util.Try[Option[Int]] = Success(None)
```

Answer (score 1):

This variant avoids rethrowing:

```
import scala.util.{Failure, Success, Try}

def swap[T](optTry: Option[Try[T]]): Try[Option[T]] =
  optTry.map(_.map(Some.apply)).getOrElse(Success(None))

swap(Some(Success(1)))
// res0: scala.util.Try[Option[Int]] = Success(Some(1))

swap(Some(Failure(new IllegalStateException("test"))))
// res1: scala.util.Try[Option[Nothing]] = Failure(java.lang.IllegalStateException: test)

swap(None)
// res2: scala.util.Try[Option[Nothing]] = Success(None)
```